# Binary to .Beep Method in c#

Tags: c#, audio, encryption, binary

Hey im trying to do something a little bit different, that is to convert a string to binary then to convert binary to a low pitch for 0 and a high pitch for a 1. However im completely lost on how to do so i was thinking of using .Beep 
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SoundHyperLink
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("imput url ");
            string stringImput = Console.ReadLine();
            string BinaryString = (ToBinaryString(Encoding.UTF8, stringImput));
            Console.WriteLine(BinaryString);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static string ToBinaryString(Encoding encoding, string text)
        {
            return string.Join("", encoding.GetBytes(text).Select(n => Convert.ToString(n, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
        }

        public void ToSoundString(string message)
        {



        }
```

If anyone could help me i would be supper happy as i cant find anything on the internet for this

Comment: sorry that i stuffed up the formatting a little bit

Comment: What is `.Beep` and where is it defined?

Comment: sorry my bad i mean Console.Beep,  but am really not to fussed if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

Define one frequency for each 0 and 1 and use it like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("imput url ");
    string stringImput = Console.ReadLine();
    string BinaryString = (ToBinaryString(Encoding.UTF8, stringImput));
    Console.WriteLine(BinaryString);
    ToSoundString(BinaryString);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string ToBinaryString(Encoding encoding, string text)
{
    return string.Join("", encoding.GetBytes(text).Select(n => Convert.ToString(n, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
}

    public static void ToSoundString(string message)
    {
        message.ToList().ForEach(f =>
        {
            switch (f)
            {
                case '0':
                    Console.Beep(500, 100);
                    break;

                case '1':
                    Console.Beep(800, 100);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```